# How to merge two object with different properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have something like this :

```
let user = [
{
    name: "step-one",
    values: {companyName: "Name", address: "company address"}
},
{
    name: "step-two",
    values: {name: "User", mobile: 0123}
},
{
    name: "step-three",
    values: [
              {file: "companyLogo", values: {active: true, fileName: "some name"}},
              {file: "avatar", values: {active: true, fileName: "file name"}}
            ]
}
]
```

I want to get only values and put them into a new object. Thus, something like :

```
let wantedResult = {
    companyName: "Name",
    address: "company address",
    name: "User",
    mobile: 0123,
    files: [
            {file: "companyLogo", values: {active: false, fileName: "some name"}},
            {file: "avatar", values: {active: false, fileName: "file name"}}
        ]
};
```

Any advice how I can do that?

Comment: Loop through them and assign them to your wantedresult? Please show us what you tried.

Comment: step three is inconsistent. Should it be `values: {files: [ {...}, {...} ] }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this!

```js
let user = [{
  name: "step-one",
  values: {
    companyName: "Name",
    address: "company address"
  }
}, {
  name: "step-two",
  values: {
    name: "User",
    mobile: 0123
  }
}, {
  name: "step-three",
  values: [{
    file: "companyLogo",
    values: {
      active: true,
      fileName: "some name"
    }
  }, {
    file: "avatar",
    values: {
      active: true,
      fileName: "file name"
    }
  }]
}]

var wantedResult = Object.assign({}, user[0].values, user[1].values, {files: user[2].values})
console.log(wantedResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hacky because of the files array, but i would do it like that:

```
var wantedResult = user.reduce((result, step) => {
    var values = Array.isArray(step.values) ? { files: step.values } : step.values;
    return Object.assign({}, result, values)
}, {});
```

Of course it'll work only for that kind of structure you provided. If you have more objects that have an array in the 'values' property, you'll need to rethink the approach.

Comment: And as iblamefish mentioned in the comment above, it would make much more sense if you change the structure of the 'step-three' to be consistent and have an object in the 'values' property instead of an array. In that case you can remove the var values assignment from my code and just use the object assign with step.values.

Answer (score 0):

Step 3 is inconsistent with the others. If possible, make it consistent to have: `values: files: [ { file1_data }, { file2_data } ]`.

After fixing the inconsistency, you can iterate through each of the steps and add the new properties to the result.

```
let wantedResult = user.reduce(function(result, spec) {
  Object.keys(spec.values).forEach(function(key) {
     result[key] = spec.values[key];
  });
  return result;
}, {});
```

---

If not possible to change step 3, you can make it a bit less clean:

```
let wantedResult = user.reduce(function(result, spec) {
  if (spec.name === "step-three") {
    result.files = spec.values;
  }
  else {
    Object.keys(spec.values).forEach(function(key) {
       result[key] = spec.values[key];
    });
  }
  return result;
}, {});
```